# Python OpenNLP Wrapper – Tokenizer stops at \n

Tags: python, nlp, opennlp

I (working on OS X) have a problem concerning this OpenNLP wrapper for python: https://github.com/rohithb/openNLP-python-wrapper

For some reason, the Sentence Detector does not work, using this wrapper. I am ok with that and just switched to a sentence detector provided by NLTK. The trouble starts when I feed the output back into the OpenNLP Tokenizer. Here is some example code:

```
import opennlp
import nltk

token = opennlp.OpenNLP("/Users/sven/apache-opennlp-1.6.0", "TokenizerME", "en-token.bin")
pos = opennlp.OpenNLP("/Users/sven/apache-opennlp-1.6.0", "POSTagger", "en-pos-maxent.bin")

def pipeline(start_with, str):
if start_with == "token":
    return pos.parse(token.parse(str).decode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
elif start_with == "pos":
        return pos.parse(str).decode('utf-8')
else:
    str = '\n'.join(nltk.sent_tokenize(str))
    return pos.parse(token.parse(str).decode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
```

As you can see, under the last "else" statement, I concat each sentence using \n as a seperator. I did this to mimic the output format of the OpenNLP Sentence Splitter as described here: http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.sentdetect.detection

Problem is, the OpenNLP Tokenizer stops working after the first sentence and gives only the result for this one. Example:

```
teststr = ("This is a sentecene. And this is yet another one.")
pipeline("",teststr)
```

OUT:

```
'This_DT is_VBZ a_DT sentecene_NN ._.'
```

Any Idea why this happens or what a possible solution could be? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any Idea why this happens

From [OpenNLP docs](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.parser.parsing.api):

> The parser expect a whitespace tokenized sentence.

The output of sentence detector *command line tool* is one sentence per line. The output of sentence detector *API* is an array of strings, one sentence per string, which is much more sensible.

To parse each sentence, don't concatenate, just do it in a loop.

Comment: Exactly as @Amadan told. The parser expects a single sentence. So just use `nltk.sent_tokenize(str)` and iterate through that list.  Also that wrapper implementation is really basic. So go through the code and make necessary changes.